# Why doesn't this rememberUser() function work?

Tags: php, cookies

I have written a function to remember the user that has just logged in. It looks to me that it should work, but no Idea why it doesn't work. The problem is that the cookie doesn't get made when I look into my browser's stored cookies.

This is the function I'm talking about:

```
function rememberUser($id) {

    $mysqli = new mysqli('bla', 'blabla', 'blablablaa', 'blaaaaa');
    if(mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        echo "Connection Failed: " . mysqli_connect_errno();
        exit();
    }
    $remember = md5(uniqid(mt_rand(),true));
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE USERS SET USER_REMEMBER_KEY = ?    WHERE USER_ID = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param('si', $remember, $id);
    $stmt->execute();
    setcookie("remember", $remember, time()+60*60*24*30, "/", "www.someSite.com", false, true);
}
```

I should mention that the query works fine and `USER_REMEMBER_KEY` is stored fine in the DB. So the problem is really the cookie, I think.

Does anyone see the problem here? Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE:** I'm using Google Chrome BETA version 19.xx

Comment: you *think*? have you checked it?

Comment: Of course I've checked my DB to see the key was generated and it was. And as I mentioned in the question I've checked stored cookies in my browser and it isn't there. I thought my explanation was pretty clear :)

Comment: Can you check the Set-Cookie response header? You should be able to view the headers with your browser's developer tools. Guesses at the problem: the domain is wrong, or you've already output some content (so it can't send further headers).

Comment: @Nick I just looked in Developer tool and then Network tab and I don't see any response cookies. There's 1 request cookie, but that's from something else. And about "header already sent" warning/error, if that happens I would at least get a warning and then I can see the response in the console.

Answer (score 1):

Are you running this locally? Chrome doesn't support cookies locally.

Comment: No I'm not running this locally.